# Lazy Loading a service using oclazyload

Tags: oclazyload

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="testApp.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Lazy load succeded if you can see 'Hello world' below</h3>
<div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">
    <button ng-click="fun()">Start</button>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module("LazyLoadTest", ["oc.lazyLoad"])
        .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile) {

            $scope.fun=function(MyService){
                $ocLazyLoad.load("testApp.js").then(function() { //loading a module
                    console.log('loaded!!'+$scope);
                    var el, elToAppend,elToAppend2;
                    elToAppend = $compile('<say-hello to="world"></say-hello>')($scope); //appending it to div
                    el = angular.element('#example');
                    console.log(el);
                    el.append(elToAppend)

                    //el.append(elToAppend2);

                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('errr');
                    console.error(e);
                })
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is the module which is to be loaded at run time. Able to load Directive but need some help to load service.
 How to laxyload the service defined in testApp.js?
  Please help me out with this